# I need to write a string that contains only numbers from 0 to 9

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements

So i have this project where i need to write a mutator method that changes a person's phone number only if the phone number contains numbers from 0 to 9 and no letters or any other things. The type of the phone number is string and i tried using conditional statements. If the mobile contains anything other than numbers then nothing should happen. this is what i got so far:

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
if(mobile.matches("[a-zA-z]+")){
 }
 else{      
        this.mobile = mobile;
 }

}
```

thanks

Comment: What is your question? But let me ask you a question: If you want to check is string is all digits (0-9), why not check that, i.e. `matches("[0-9]+")`?\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex pattern should be `[0-9]+`

Comment: if this is it then the if condition should be reversed right?

Comment: Thanks. that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for anything that isn't a number then the pattern is `\D`. That just means non-digit and is a shorthand for `[^0-9]`

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html